# getting SSH Errors while trying to execute ping statement to multiple IPs' using thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm new to python programming and trying to use threads for my work. I have a ping function which takes an IP address and ssh handle and returns True if the ping is successful. Since the no. of IP's to check connectivity is large, checking ping status for each IP takes a lot of time. so i use thread to check the ping status which i thought will fasten my process.

My requirement is to invoke thread which will call ping function and store the return value of ping result of each IP

The code that I have written is as follows:

````
def pingResult(ssh_handle,ip, count = 10):
    print('Ping To IP {0}'.format(ip))
    cmd = 'ping {0} -c 10'.format(ip)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_handle.exec_command(cmd)
    pat  = r'(\d+)\s+\w+\s+\w+,\s+(\d+)\s+\w+,\s+(\d+)%\s+\w+\s+\w+'
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print(line)
        match = re.search(pat,line,re.I)
        if match:
            loss = int(match.group(3))
            if loss < 20:
                return True
    return False```
````

```
for thread_id, ip in enumerate(iplist):
        thread_name ='t'+str(thread_id)
        print('The value of thread_name is : {0}'.format(thread_name))
        thread_name = threading.Thread(target = pingResult, args = (res[1],ip))
        thread_list.append(thread_name)

        print('The value of thread_list is  {0}'.format(thread_list))


    for th in thread_list:
        th.start()
```

i get the following error while executing this piece of code.

```
Secsh channel 10 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited
Exception in thread Thread-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py”, line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
Secsh channel 11 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited
```

I tried to google it and tried few possibilities but my attempts are in Vain. Can some one kindly help me with this.

Is this something which is achievable using threads or is there a better way to address this?

Comment: what does the **remote var log** report? ```/var/log/auth.log```

Comment: What happens when you try to run just a single ping without threading for the IP address on which the threading method failed?

Comment: i dont have a file with that name [root@localhost v2.84]# cat /var/log/auth.log
cat: /var/log/auth.log: No such file or directory
[root@localhost v2.84]#

Comment: without threading it works. i have cross checked that.

Comment: presumably `ssh_handle` is a `Paramiko` handle and your `exec_command` is opening a separate channel for each concurrent ping.  this will result in your solution doing enormous amounts of extra work for a, presumably simple ICMP/UDP ping.  I'd suggest fundamentally rethinking your approach

Comment: sure. I will give it a try